# Xaml не видит свойства из ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Почему в Xaml не срабатывают подсказки с названиями свойств VM-ки? Но если ввести правильное название свойства то все компилируется и работает хорошо.

Привязку VM к окну делаю так :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new MainVm()
        }.Show();
    }
}

public class MainVm : VmBase
{
    private string _input;

    public string Input
    {
        get { return _input; }
        set { _input = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="WarehouseClient2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Input}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Дайте больше кода. Этот код правильный.

Comment: @VladD, Добавил код. Свойство Input редактор вообще не видит, но если его ввести самому то все работает.

Comment: А во время выполнения видит?

Comment: @VladD, да, во время выполнения видит.

Comment: Вы просто забыли объявить ожидаемый тип контекста. Для примера - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394295

Comment: @Monk: Ого! Напишите ответ, это важно.

Comment: @Monk, Если б забыл, а так просто не знал :) Напишите ответ, решение помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WPF XAML представления можно переиспользовать. Поэтому, если вы пишите формочку под конкретную ВМ - её тип можно указать, чтобы intellisense подсказывал вам названия свойств. Простой пример на коленке за пару минут, ВМ в одно свойство:

```
  public class ViewModel
  {
    public string IamProperty { get; set; }
  }
```

И контрол под неё:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LocalizationExample"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IamProperty}"/>
</UserControl>
```

intellisense подсказывает, какое свойство можно подставить:

[image: Пример]

### Неправильное решение проблемы

на самом деле, можно ещё сделать вот так:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IamProperty}"/>
```

intellisense будет работать. Только вот DataContext так создается в разметке и потом можно огрести кучу неприятных проблем, если его никто не ждёт. Видел не раз в работающем коде, поэтому отдельно дописываю.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код правильный.

Проблема вот в чём: XAML, в отличие от C# — слабо типизированный язык. Поэтому на этапе редактирования ещё неизвестно, какой реальный тип попадёт в `DataContext`, у будут ли у него нужные свойства. Например, вы можете написать

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
    window.DataContext = new MainVm();
else
    window.DataContext = "привет";
```